# How to enlist the regulators to defend Big Town?

Tags: fallout-3

A number of guides and forums mention that, with the Lawbringer perk, the Regulators can help defend Big Town during "Big Trouble in Big Town". I have a character with "Lawbringer", but haven't seen this option when talking with Red or Sonora Cruz. How does one bring the Regulators in to Big Town to fight the super mutant attack? Does this take the place of one of the other defense options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This is impossible.

I suspect that the person who posted this bit of information on the wiki page for the quest Big Trouble in Little Town (https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Big_Trouble_in_Big_Town) was using some form of a Regulator overhaul mod.

The Steam version of Fallout 3 includes an installation file for the Garden of Eden Creation Kit, which allowed me to have a look through this quest's conditions and all dialogue associated with it. In short, there is nothing in the base game that has Red refer to the Regulators in any way, and the only thing that the Regulators do it buy the fingers of evil dead people off you, which is why I was able to find multiple Regulator overhaul mods with just a quick search.

Here is a screenshot of the quest's dialogue tree. You can see on the right side the player's values that the quest checks, and there is no check for a Lawbringer perk:
[image: Quest dialogue tree for the quest Big Trouble in Little Town.]